# QGLContext create fail

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

In QGLWidget after OpenGL initialization I create another context:

```
QGLContext* _glContext =
  new QGLContext(QGLContext::currentContext()->format());
_glContext->create();
```

And `create` returns 0. Why?